# Responsive images - Resizing a image on different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, response, media-queries

I am using http://www.getskeleton.com/ at the framework for my site. I want a image to resize on different screen sizes e.g. iPhone. Does anyone know the easiest way to do this? I've done a google search and been given too many options to know which is best. What am i after is as the screen gets smaller the image is changed for a smaller one.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky question : there are lots of way which have been devised by the design community, each with different pros/cons. There's no "perfect" one (i/e a new img tag with media queries, but a [working group](http://www.w3.org/community/respimg) is adressing the issue)

Ma favorite way to do it is the one described here : http://headlondon.com/our-thoughts/technology/posts/creating-responsive-images-using-the-noscript-tag

You'll have to adapt their script, because it's a ruby helper gem, not plain html/js.

Comment: After a little digging i found that in the framework there was a method to do just what i wanted.  img.scale-with-grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; } thanks for your reply

Comment: Will it remplace your image according to the device resolution ?

Comment: IF that is your answer you should add it as an answer and accept it, so that others searching for it can find it.

Answer (score 1):

You will find

```
img.scale-with-grid {max-width: 100%;height: auto; }
```

just user "scale-with-grid" in your images and it will do the trick

Comment: I found  img.scale-with-grid {width: 100%;height: auto; } works better